# How to mock after setup dagger-android 2.15 when writing espresso tests?

Tags: android, kotlin, mocking, android-espresso, dagger

If we just use plain dagger 2. In the `application` class, we will have a property which holds the `AppComponent`. Then we can swap it during espresso tests.

But when I setup my project using `dagger-android 2.15`. Things becomes more implicit if adopt too much Dagger magic. The code is more clean, but makes testing a little bit hard.

**This is the `application` class:**

```
class App : DaggerApplication() {
    override fun applicationInjector(): AndroidInjector<out DaggerApplication> {
        return DaggerAppComponent
            .builder()
            .create(this)
            .build()
    }
}
```

**This is the HomeActivity**

```
class HomeActivity : DaggerAppCompatActivity() {
    @Inject
    lateinit var userPreference: UserPreference

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)

        if (!this.userPreference.memberRegistered) {
            goToActivity(EntryActivity::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

Take this code for example. How to mock that injected `userPreference.memberRegistered` Which could be a HTTP call underneath?

Comment: I actually just wrote a blog post about this yesterday: https://dev.to/autonomousapps/the-daggerandroid-missing-documentation-33kj

Comment: @AutonomousApps Read it! Thanks! Really great tutorial! Seems just need to replace DaggerApplication with interface.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I wrote a blog post that explains how to do this just yesterday: https://dev.to/autonomousapps/the-daggerandroid-missing-documentation-33kj

I don't intend to repeat the entire post for this answer (it's hundreds of words and lines of code to properly set up a test harness with Dagger), but to attempt to summarize:

1. Add a custom application class in the `debug` source set (I assume it would also work in the `androidTest` source set, but I have not tried this).
2. You also need to reference this application in a `AndroidManifest.xml` in the same source set.
3. Create a "Test component" in your androidTest class that extends from your production top-level component and build it.
4. Use that test component to inject your application, which means you've just replaced your entire Dagger dependency graph with a new one you've defined just for the test suite.
5. Profit.

Comment: Seems hacky to me. also if you add this new application in debug , that means you are using your mocked testing dependencies in debug mode as well as in test mode where in theory you usually run your prod code in debug mode so you can umm debug the prod code

Comment: Is there a way to just create a Application that is used only in test?

Comment: You obviously can't inject mock dependencies in a dev build because you would never include test libs in your prod code.

Comment: Yea so the above wont work! you will be using testable mocks on your debug dev code!

Comment: No, you won't. You have no idea what you're talking about and I'm done now.

Comment: yes u will and its the wrong way, your way of thinking is flawed. use dagger mocks instead and do it properly. This is a terrible idea and everry time you use a debug version of your app it will use this mocked components etc located inside your ApplicationDebug class.

Answer (score 1):

For those who is interested in this, I got a [blog](http://www.albertgao.xyz/2018/04/24/how-to-mock-dagger-android-injection-in-instrumented-tests-with-kotlin/) with step by step detail for this:

Basically, the idea is:

1. You still generate instances for injection in @Module
2. But We’ll create new @Component A only for testing
3. This @Component will have a method to get that @Module
4. During tests, we swap the @Component that the application use with our component A

Then things are easy:

- Without DaggerMock

  - In the @Module, instead of return real instance, you just return mockito mock.
- With DaggerMock

  - You declare the type you want to swap and mock it
  - You can then use the mock.
  - No need to change the @Module

It inspires by @AutonomousApps 's solution, but the differences are now you don't need to write the @Component, @Module for each test class.

Comment: I actually consider it a feature that I have a component per test. That gives me total control over each test. They can be as deep or shallow as I like (unit tests vs end to end tests).

Comment: Exactly, but DaggerMock will make it easier if you only need to mock the providers from the @Module, I just reuse the AppComponentForTest through the whole tests... Anyway, thanks! without your blog, will be very tricky to work it out. :D

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

After trying several approaches, [this](https://android.jlelse.eu/how-to-inject-mock-dependencies-into-android-components-using-dagger-androidinjector-e274c8f6a9a6) is the only one that worked for me.